# Linking image not working due to skew scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

I have added some skew scrolling to this project and it has recently caused some problems for me. The return of app.js file shows the Header tag right before the `<div ref={scrollContainer} className="scroll">`. Once it is placed before the `scrollContainer` the links work perfectly fine. I have some images I want on the front page and the problem is that it only links to another page if I put if before the `scollcontainer` div, but when I put it under, it as seen below in the Home function, then it results in the skew controls working on the images, but the links not working. Once I put the image tag before the `scrollcontainer` div, like the header, then it is able to redirect properly, but it wouldn't scroll down to all images. I was wondering how I could solve this problem. I could add more code or explain it better if needed.

App.js file:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles/App.scss";
import Header from "./components/header";
import useWindowSize from "./hooks/useWindowSize";
import Images from "./images/images";

function App() {
  const size = useWindowSize();
  const app = useRef();
  const scrollContainer = useRef();

  const data = {
    ease: 0.1,
    current: 0,
    previous: 0,
    rounded: 0
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => skewScrolling());
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    setBodyHeight();
  }, [size.height]);
  const setBodyHeight = () => {
    document.body.style.height = `${
      scrollContainer.current.getBoundingClientRect().height
    }px`;
  };
  const skewScrolling = () => {
    data.current = window.scrollY;
    data.previous += (data.current - data.previous) * data.ease;
    data.rounded = Math.round(data.previous * 100) / 100;
    const difference = data.current - data.rounded;
    const acceleration = difference / size.width;
    const velocity = +acceleration;
    const skew = velocity * 20;
    scrollContainer.current.style.transform = `translate3d(0, -${data.rounded}px, 0) skewY(${skew}deg)`;
    requestAnimationFrame(() => skewScrolling());
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <div ref={app} className="App">
      <Header/>
      <div ref={scrollContainer} className="scroll">
      <div className='home'>
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </div>
        <Switch><Route exact path='/about' component={About} /></Switch>
        <Switch><Route exact path='/info' component={Info} /></Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function About() {
  return <h3>Feel free to reach us.</h3>;
}

function Home() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <div className='container'>
    <div className="title">
            <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
      <Images/>
      <Switch><Route exact path='/info' component={Info} /></Switch>
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Info() {
  return <h4>More Info</h4>;
}


export default App;
```